# Ads on ARC Welder / ChromeOS

Tags: android, admob, google-chrome-arc

According to this: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc#bestpractices Ads served through the Google Play Services API should work on ARC Welder but all I get in my app is the test banner as shown in the picture: [image]

Is there anything I need to do to make this work? As far as I can tell everything works, the ad is loaded like it does on Android but it just doesn't serve real ads. I'm using the exact same code to load ads on ARC Welder as I do on Android (including the same adUnitId). The same happens if you run the app on a Chromebook so it's not an ARC Welder issue. Interstitial ads don't show at all.

Here's how the the ad is loaded:

```
AdRequest.Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder();
if (Debug.DEBUG_MODE) {
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
    adRequest.addTestDevice("F5281A44BC3A9D2A1F8610A73C7C5A3D");
    adRequest.addTestDevice("2E76737226676685E8D099929CDE097C");
    adRequest.addTestDevice("BD1C0F31A686C467D35C92281DFB80D6");
    adRequest.addTestDevice("407FB1B6C16E3A3E7F74E5F91DA17CA3");
}

admobView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override public void onAdLoaded() {
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});

admobView.loadAd(adRequest.build());
```

Debug.DEBUG_MODE is false so the addTestDevice calls are never executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Mobile Ads SDK always returns test ads when an emulator requests AdMob fill (to prevent production ads being used during development), and I bet that ARC triggers that behavior.

I do not currently know of a workaround, though I should mention that this would not affect those loading ads from Doubleclick for Publishers (which also uses the Mobile Ads SDK).

Comment: As mentioned in the question, it's not just in ARC Welder but on a Chromebook too (productive app). I'd assume that the wrapper ARC Welder puts around my Android app doesn't qualify as an emulator.

Comment: According to the SDK Team: "The implementation of ARC Welder and Android apps on Chrome OS cause requests to the ads SDK to register as coming from an emulator. There is currently no workaround for this. However, we do hope to push a change to an upcoming release of our SDK that will allow for live ads on these platforms ." (http://bit.ly/1O4h5Rx). So while your answer is based on assumptions it's still partly correct and I therefore mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this

```
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
```

from your AdRequest Builder and you should see live ads.

EDIT:- Tried this with my WeWorkRemotely android app and it works fine after removing Emulator as a test device-

[image]

Comment: I'm not setting test devices so that's no answer either

Comment: Ok that is weird, because I recently tried ARC welder with one of my apps and it was showing test banners. Then I removed Emulator as a test device and it started showing live ads. Do you mind showing your AdRequest builder?

Comment: I added the code that loads the ad. As mentioned in the question the Debug.DEBUG_MODE is false so the addTestDevice calls are  ever executed. I also removed the if statement completely (including what's in the if statement) but to no avail.

Comment: Beats me. I tried the same code and it works fine for me. Just added a screenshot of one the apps I tried this on. Though I am still not sure if we should put up ads on chrome apps, because these are treated as if running in an emulator and ad clicks on them may trick Google into thinking that you are clicking on your own ads inside emulator. That might get your admob/adsense account blocked.

Comment: What platform are you running the ARC Welder on?

Comment: I have both windows and mac. Works same on both of them. Screenshot is of Windows, just checked on MBP and I can see ads.

Comment: Do you use mediation or just plain Admob banner ads? How do you inflate the ad view? XML or code? Just trying to figure out a difference between the two setups.

Comment: No mediation, plain admob smart banners. my code is same as yours. Create a AdRequest using the builder, add test devices (remove emulator), build and load. My view is an always visible layout.

Comment: I'm not able to test right this second, but could the difference in what you're seeing be related to the version of chrome/arc welder you're using?  Is it canary/dev channel (which I believe loads a newer version of AW) or is it the stable version?  Maybe later I'll try removing the emulator from the list of test devices too to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: My chrome version 41.0.2272.118
It is not Canary.